# .HTAccess - How to modify a url with under score in file name as sub directory?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Lets say I have a directory with the following files:

```
news_sports.html
news_food.html
news.html
index.html
```

How would I make it using .Htaccess so that when my website is being accessed by http://example.com/en-gb/news/sports it get's it out of news_sports.html and http://example.com/en-gb/news/food reads out of news_food.html and http://example.com/en-gb/news (with or without the slash at the end) reads out of news.html

My current .Htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1_$2\.html -f
RewriteRule ^en-gb/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ $1_$2.html [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^en-gb(.*)$ /site/views/en/gb/$1 [L,NC]
```

Directory Structure

```
HTDOCS
  ->site
    ->views
       ->en
         ->gb
            ->index.html
            ->news.html
            ->news_sport.html
            ->news_food.html
         ->us
         ->au
```

To summarise this, I want it so that when a user enters my site with the following url: http://example.com/en-gb/news/sports apache needs to serve from HTDOCS ->site->views->en->gb->news_sports.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a new rule for underscore condition:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^en-gb/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /site/views/en/gb/$1_$2.html [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^en-gb(.*)$ /site/views/en/gb/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80422/discussion-between-anubhava-and-user3052975).